# Scraping Metacritic: Use a condition to scrape nodes with Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, conditional-statements

I'm writing a code to **scrape** all the review of https://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-4/red-dead-redemption-2/user-reviews.

I'm getting difficulties in **scraping** the comments because of the "Expand" button that appears for long comments.

I've managed to **scrape** the long comments, but haven't been able to **scrape** all the others:

```
review <- html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'span[class="blurb blurb_expanded"]'))
```

I have found a code using Beautifulsoup but am clueless for doing the same on Rvest

```
if review.find('span', class_='blurb blurb_expanded'):
        review_dict['review'].append(review.find('span', class_='blurb blurb_expanded').text)
    else:
        review_dict['review'].append(review.find('div', class_='review_body').find('span').text)
```

How do you do something similar on Rvest? How do you add a condition on what you want to **scrape** ? How do you **scrape** all the non-extended comments?

Thank you!!

Comment: Including the critics' reviews?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Comment: haha thanks! @balmy

Answer (score 0):

You don't need conditional logic. You do need an user-agent header. Then you can select the reviews by class (`review_body`) that are under the product reviews (class `product_reviews`). Using `html_text2()` you can retain nice formatting for the `br` elements.

```
library(httr)

headers <- c( "user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0")

r <- httr::GET(url = "https://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-4/red-dead-redemption-2/user-reviews", httr::add_headers(.headers = headers)) %>%
  content()

reviews <- r %>% html_elements('.product_reviews .review_body') %>% html_text2() %>% lapply(. ,function(x){gsub('… Expand','',x)})
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I've encountered a couple of addtional issues now:

1/ Formating: In my data, there are "\r" where there's a line break in the source, and backlashes around some quote marks. Any option I can add to elegantly remove them? Or should I just make an additional function to remove these?

2/ "Long Reviews": Unfortunately, this doesn't exactly retrieve the long reviews, but it actually merge the Collapsed+Extended reviews. Any workaround you can think of?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, 1) Is this just a string representation thing and when you actually write out that content to file you get the new lines? 2) Are you saying there is missing info or repeated info? Is there an example review you could mention where the problem is present?

Comment: Hi, 1/ it's actually there in the file, but I managed to clean it with .Replace 2/ Yes, for instance in reviews[2] from your code, the text is "The 10 score reviews here must be some hardcore fanboys or [rest of the collapsed comment]The 10 score reviews here must be some hardcore fanboys or [rest of the extended comment]".